# Passing String from C to Ada via C Interpreter (VxWorks)

Tags: c++, c, ada, vxworks

I'm trying to pass a string from C to Ada by using the C interpreter in a telnet window to a VxWorks box.

Interface.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

extern void Ada_SetNewAddress(char*);

extern "C" void SetNewAddrBroker(char* ipAddress);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Interface.cpp

```
#include "Interface.h"
#include <stdio>

extern "C" void SetNewAddrBroker(char* ipAddress)
{
    printf("We passed the value -> %s", ipAddress);
    Ada_SetNewAddress(ipAddress);
    printf("Ada was called!\n");
}
```

Streamer.ads

```
with Interfaces.C;
with Interfaces.C.Strings;

package Streamer is
    procedure Initialize;
    procedure SetNewAddress(str : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr);
    pragma Export (C, SetNewAddress, "Ada_SetNewAddress");
end Streamer;
```

Streamer.adb

```
package body Streamer is
    Socket : Socket_Type;
    DefaultAddr : String := "127.0.0.1";
    Address : Sock_Addr_Type := (Family_Inet, Inet_Addr(DefaultAddr), 1024);
    Buffer : Stream_Access;

    procedure Initialize is
    begin
        Create_Socket(Socket, Family_Inet, Socket_Datagram);
        Buffer := Stream(Socket, Address);
    end;

    procedure SetNewAddress(str : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr)
        cstar : String := Interfaces.C.Strings.Value(str);
    begin
        Address := (Family_Inet, Inet_Addr(cstar), 1024);
        Buffer := Stream(socket, Address);
    end;
end Streamer;
```

When I call the C function SetNewAddrBroker("192.168.1.1") I get a 'data access' error, this is via telnet to the VxWorks machine that this code exists on, the Ada program is the main task, so I know it's not the missing "adainit() and adafinal()" calls. I can't figure out why it's throwing a random data access error. I can use putty or teraterm for the telnet client if that matters, both throw the same error.

**THE ERROR OUTPUT**

```
    We passed -> 192.168.1.1
    data access
    Exception current instruction address: 0x002e3ab0
    ............
    trcStack aborted: error in top frame
    Shell task 'tShellRem1' restarted...
```

Examining, the instruction that threw the error

```
    0x2e3ab0 stw r30,8(r9)
```

I do not know assembly but I imagine this is trying to store the string in a place that is too small?

I need to set the IP of the broker for the client at runtime, the Ada is the client, and the broker is just on my LAN. I want to be able to telnet to the Ada client and just update the ip address, but the only interface exposed to me is the C interpreter for the VxWorks box, so I'm stuck with interfacing with this.

VxWorks Version 6.3

Comment: You have a C interpreter?  It's not out of the question, but C is ordinarily a compiled language.

Comment: Or maybe I should say a C++ interpreter, because your code is C++, not C. (Tags edited.)

Comment: Since you want to pass a String from C/C++ to Ada, pragma Import should be used instead. Hopefully, this will fix your issue.

Comment: VxWorks versions before vs 7 indeed support a C interpreter in the "hostShell": https://usermanual.wiki/Document/vxworksclitoolsusersguide62.1564990031.pdf#G10.119991.

Comment: The function Interfaces.C.Strings.Value very probably returns its value in the GNAT Secondary Stack. Are you sure that your Ada configuration supports a Secondary Stack, and that its size is sufficient? If the call to the Ada procedure does not come from an Ada task, but from some target debugger task, the Secondary Stack may not be set up properly for this non-Ada task. To avoid using the Secondary Stack, you might try to define the parameter SetNewAddress.str as an access to a fixed-length (constrained) array of Character, add a Length parameter, and pass that slice to Inet_Addr.

Comment: If the problem is indeed the Secondary Stack, the safest course is to make SetNewAddrBroker store the string, and its length, in global statically allocated variables and then signal an Ada task to take the address from those variables. That should ensure that the Ada task has a properly defined Secondary Stack on which it can handle strings and other data of dynamic size.

Comment: @NiklasHolsti I will try your suggestion and update the question with my findings. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Have you actuallycalled `Streamer.Initialize`? (you could call it from the package's [handled sequence of statements](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-7-2.html#p2))

Comment: @SimonWright The Streamer.Initialize is called from a different Ada task (the initialization task), it is called before any of the package code is referenced in the project.

Comment: @NiklasHolsti I tried your suggestion by storing the variable and it's length in a statically allocated C structure, and the error changed from the current one to secondary_stack_ss_allocate. I then inspected the secondary stack size and it's -1, but I could not use GNAT bind or Ada calls to the Secondary Stack library in order to change it. Apparently on dynamically sized secondary stacks it will always return -1. I still can't get it to print out anything but an integer, it's only when I pass strings that I have an issue with interfacing from C -> Ada.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's a C interpreter, you're correct that my code is C++, but it's still a C interpreter, and all code on the system is treated as C during runtime iirc.

Comment: @TaylorLopez, please show the code you use to store the string and its length in a statically allocated C structure, and also the Ada code that you use to extract the string and its length from that C structure. Is the secondary-stack working when the Ada code runs for itself, and is not being called from the C interpreter via telnet? That is, has your Ada code used secondary-stack successfully before the addition of SetNewAddress?

Comment: @NiklasHolsti I'm not sure if the code as used secondary stack successfully before the addition of SetNewAddress, but we've consumed strings before in only C interface code and everything was fine. It's only the barrier of passing a string from C -> Ada via the C interpreter that throws issues.

Comment: The code @NiklasHolsti -> https://codeshare.io/DZBnMO

Comment: @TaylorLopez: There are two problems in your code, which may explain why it does not work. First, your C code is still /calling/ the Ada code (the call of Ada_SetNewAddress) which means that the Ada code is still running within the debugger/interpreter thread, which (as I said earlier) is unlikely to have a Secondary Stack defined. I suggested to _signal_ an Ada task, not call Ada code. Second, the Ada code is still calling functions (from Interfaces.C.Strings) that return String values of dynamic, rather than static, length, which still means use of the Secondary Stack. (to be continued)

Comment: I tried to write a comment continuing my preceding comment, but it was lost somehow. Anyway, its point was to say that as you, @TaylorLopez, are not sure if the Ada side has a working Secondary Stack, I will write an Answer with some suggested Ada code that should not use the Secondary Stack. That Answer I have now written.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion on changing the code in https://codeshare.io/DZBnMO such that it still calls Ada from C (instead of signalling an Ada task), but gets the string from the C structure without using Secondary Stack, because all string variables now have a statically known length:

In package Streamer, change the declaration of GetNewAddress to be:

```
subtype String_15 is String (1 .. 15);
type String_15_Ptr is access all String_15;

function GetNewAddress return String_15_Ptr;
pragma Import ( .. as before .. );
```

In package body Streamer, change SetNewAddress as follows:

```
procedure SetNewAddress
is -- (this "is" was missing from codeshare, btw)
   csize : constant Natural := Natural (GetNewAddressLen);
   cstrptr : constant String_15_Ptr := GetNewAddress;
   adaString : String_15;
begin
   for I in 1 .. csize loop
      adaString(I) := cstrptr(I);
   end loop;
   Address := (Family_Inet, Inet_Addr(adaString(1 .. csize)), 1024);
   Buffer := Stream (Socket, Address);
end;
```

Note that I haven't compiled this code, but I hope it shows the method to avoid Secondary Stack: every global and local variable must have a static size, and so must all function return-value types, but it is possible to pass slices of dynamic size as parameters (because GNAT uses pass-by-reference there).

The suggested Ada code is maybe not fully portable, because it assumes a certain correspondence between C types like "char *" and Ada types like "String_15_Ptr", but on normal architectures I expect it to work.

By the way, your C code has a potential buffer-overflow bug: SetNewAddrBroker should use strncpy(), not strcpy().

Comment: So, the code compiled, and I made the suggested change to strncpy, but unfortunately, the interpreter still throws a data access error. Even with the necessary changes to avoid the Secondary Stack it still will not correctly pass the data inserted. I'm not really sure why this is the case, it just throws a data access error. I think this is an operating system level issue with VxWorks but I can't seem to find the rationale as to why these errors occur. I appreciate all your help Niklas, if I ever find the answer I will let you know what the solution was.

Comment: Ah, too bad. Then I can only return to my suggestion that you should have the interpreter call C code that stores the string in a global variable (as your code now does), and then _signals_ an Ada task (not running under the interpreter) to pick up the string from that global variable. But first I would check if the Ada environment really supports Secondary Stack, because it is quite likely that the network (socket) libraries need it.